# Replicate netplan nameserver configuration for centos

Tags: centos7, puppet, netplan

First of a warning: I'm a junior level with little experience using centos.

I'm running a puppet environment with a few different machines some example modules I'm running is consul and [puppet-dns](https://github.com/ppouliot/puppet-dns) for the ubuntu machines I have used netplan to configure up my dns clients.

## Dns Server machine

```
  include dns::server

  # Forwarders
  dns::server::options { '/etc/bind/named.conf.options':
    dnssec_enable     => false,
    dnssec_validation => no,
    forwarders        => [ 'IP1' ],
  }

  dns::zone { 'consul':
    zone_type       => forward,
    forward_policy  => only,
    allow_forwarder => [ '127.0.0.1 port 8600' ],
  }
```

## DNS Client setup

```
  /^(Debian|Ubuntu)$/: { 
  class { 'netplan':
    config_file   => '/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml',
    ethernets     => {
      'ens3' => {
        'dhcp4'       => true,
        'nameservers' => {
          'search'    => ['node.consul'],
          'addresses' => [ "$dir_ip" ],
        }
      }
    },
    netplan_apply => true,
  }
```

In order to replicate this on Centos7, I came accross ifcfg files
(/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3) however, I am not sure how to replicate the result from above within one of this files. Does anyone have experience with this ?

Comment: So you want to configure CentOS 7 *clients* for use with your existing server?

Comment: Are you using your own `netplan` module?  If not, then which?

Comment: And are you asking how to use netplan on CentOS, or just how to configure CentOS as a client of your DNS server?

Comment: netplan: 'zehweh-netplan',   '0.1.9'

Yes I wanted to use an existing server with my centos 7 machine. After some read up I ended up editing `/etc/resolve.conf`with a nameserver and search. 

This worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading, I decided to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` with the help of puppetmod: `saz-resolv_conf`

```
 class { 'resolv_conf':
      nameservers => ["$dir_ip"],
      searchpath  => ['node.consul'],
  }
```

I was a bit skeptical about this at first since the file had automated items from OpenStack, however, everything is working as expected.